# On back, kill activity without delaying main thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'm running a simple application that on load shows a list of items, when clicked opens up a video player playing the media.

I'm having an issue that when destroying the player and returning to the list view, that there is a long delay before any events are being registered. This is due to the tear down of the player taking a few seconds.

I had asked the support crew and they recommended the best way to go about it was to simply hide the player and show again when new media was clicked but I've been reading into threads and it seems like this might be the best approach to use instead? I'm not exactly sure how they work though.
If I kill the player service in onDestroy will initiating a new one still be held up?

```
public class DemoPlayer extends Activity {

    private Player player;
    private SeekBarScrubber scrubber;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.player);
        // Set the media url holder
        String mediaUrl = "";

        player = new Player(
                // inject player container view into ADK Player
                (ViewGroup) this.findViewById(R.id.tpPlayer)
        );

        // Build application UI
        scrubber = (SeekBarScrubber) findViewById(R.id.scrubber);
        scrubber.setMediaPlayerControl(player.asMediaPlayerControl());

        final Activity activity = this;

        try {
            URI mediaUri = new URI(mediaUrl);
            player.playReleaseUrl(mediaUri);
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Invalid URL");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Issue loading media");
            alertDialog.setCancelable(true);
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

               if (player != null)
                   player.getLifecycle().destroy();
               player = null;
           }
        }).start();
        ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) this.findViewById(R.id.tpPlayer);
        viewGroup.removeView(scrubber);
        scrubber = null;
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            finish();// call finish() on click of back button
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

}
```

**TL;DR:** How to kill player without holding up the UI thread since it takes a few seconds to destroy the player. Also will loading a new player quickly cause issues?

Currently get the error below

```
failed access media controller because player thread is shutdown
Skipped 374 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Answer (score 0):

The player is attached to the view when the view is created not the other way around. Therefore i think that your best option is to move the player to a *singleton* and start/stop him regardless of the activity lifecycle. of course u can do the shutdown on back thread (i suggest u read about threadpools and executers because i rarely see *Thread.start()* on android.

also:

> ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) this.findViewById(R.id.tpPlayer);
>           viewGroup.removeView(scrubber);
>           scrubber = null;

this is unnecessary.

Comment: Doesn't have to be on the UI thread, I've tried moving it to a new thread but it doesn't seem to have any impact, I'm new to java/android so I'm most likely just going about it incorrectly